# Boolean Logic - anything complemented twice is equal to original for multiple variables

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I know that `A + A'B == A + B` but does it work for `B' + BC'D = B' + C'D` ?

Also, am I able to do `A' + AB = A' + B`?

Where `A'` is the negation of A.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that `A + A'B == A + B` but does it work for `B' + BC'D = B' + C'D` ?

Yes. The two equations are effectively the same, just with different names for variables.

`A` in first equation = `B'` in second equation.

`B` in first equation = `C'D` in second equation.

> Also, am I able to do `A' + AB = A' + B`?

Yes. Again, the two equations are effectively the same, just with different variable names.

`A` in first equation = `A'` in third (most recent) equation.

For future reference... when in doubt, just make a truth table (or k-map, if necessary) to figure out the simplest equivalent solution.